# What is [0] and [1..-1] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What do `[0]` and `[1..-1]` mean in the following code?

```
def capitalize(string) 
  puts "#{string[0].upcase}#{string[1..-1]}"
end
```

Comment: Read about different ways to access individual characters and substrings in strings using [`String#[] method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could point out what, *precisely* is unclear to you in the documentation of `String#[]`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't run into the same problem again.

Comment: @JörgWMittag In my case, I've come to this looking for the point behind the 1..-1 sequence, if that's helpful. This code bit comes from [this Codeacademy exercise](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-ruby/lessons/methods-blocks-sorting/exercises/how-blocks-differ-from-methods?action=resume_content_item), which I'm working through.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`string[0]` is a new string that contains the first character of `string`.
It is, in fact, syntactic sugar for `string.[](0)`, i.e. calling the method [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) on the [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html) object stored in the variable `string` with argument `0`.

The [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method also accepts a [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Range.html) as argument, to extract a substring. In this case, the lower bound of range is the index where the substring starts and the upper bound is the index where the substring ends. Positive values count the characters from the beginning of the string (starting with `0`), negative values count the characters from the end of the string (`-1` denotes the last character).

The call `string[1..-1]` (`string.[](1..-1)`) returns a new string that is initialized with the substring of `string` that starts with the second character of `string` (`1`) and ends with its last character.

Put together, `string[0].upcase` is the uppercase version of the first character of `string`, `string[1..-1]` is the rest of `string` (everything but the first character).

Read more about different ways to access individual characters and substrings in strings using [`String#[] method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: The OP might not be aware that – in the given code – `[0]` and `[1..-1]` are method calls. Maybe you should clarify that first.